# OSMC- Problem only with music playback

Tags: pi-2, osmc, media-server, media

I made a nice mediacenter with my raspberry B+. It connects wireless to a shared folder in my main pc with SMB protocol, and everything works like a charm.

The movies play without any interruption and the library is updated in a matter of around 2 minutes; I'm very satisfied.

The problem kicks in when I try to play music. I shared my library with SMB protocol but the library update takes forever (matter of many hours for around 40GB). It's not just a scraper problem, as when I play an album sometimes the system freezes for some minute and then the playback starts again, and it happens quite often.

I always thought video playback could have been harder to work flawlessy, but my problem really relates music: it's not stable and I can't understand why.

What can I try?

Comment: 40GB of music contains hugely more individual items than the equivalent quantity of video, which is plausibly why your library updates are taking so long. It's been a while since I used a pi B for a media centre, but I do remember getting substantial improvements on moving to a pi 2. Worth upgrading if you can.

Comment: that's ok for the update, and i don't matter as I do it only once in a month. But I'd expect my mp3 playback to be faster than full hd movies!

Comment: Are you connected to the library via SMB? Meaning the files are stored off the RPi?

Comment: Yes, the movies and the music is stored in the same external 2.5 hd. I adopted this solution as the hd drains too much current and the pi cannot provide  1A or more.